# Getting input field value in unity then Debug.Log ing it

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I am creating a test project in Unity & I have an input field and a button. I would like to take the text from the input and simply `Debug.Log` to the Unity Console onclick of a button. All the examples show the variables and functions but don't show HOW they are getting the input to the variable. I already have UI set up including linking the function to the button. Is there some way I can give it an `id` like in JavaScript & HTML? I dont want to do anything fancy. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class main : MonoBehaviour
{

    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void debugInput() {
        Debug.Log()
    }
}
```

I would like to pass the variable in the `Debug.Log` in the `debugInput` function.
Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The InputField uses a callback for entering text to an input field called [`OnSubmit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField.OnSubmit.html). If you would rather print every frame the user enters new text, there is also [`OnValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html).

These callbacks can be assigned in the inspector by selecting your `InputField` object. The inspector should look something like the below photo.

[image: Example Inspector]

Simply click the **+** button, drag in the object that has the script that has the method you would like to callback. Make sure when selecting it to choose it from the `Dynamic String` list as it will auto pass in the string you have in the `InputField` to your function. You will need to change your code to take a string parameter tho.

```
public void debugInput(string str) 
{
     Debug.Log(str)
}
```

[image: Dynamic Listener]

If you would rather set these values through code, you can do so by adding new listener delegates to your object. I can post a snippet for this solution if you would rather keep everything in a script.

Edit: I am using a TMPro Input Field, but the above example still works for a Unity UI Input Field. Instead of `OnSubmit`, you can use `OnEndEdit`. You can also add your own [`EventTriggers`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html) to use `OnSubmit` if you want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by dynamic string list? And yes, can you provide a snippet for it all to be in a script?

Comment: Follow along with the steps in the editor. The image I posted shows exactly what I mean. When assigning a method as a callback to the `InputField`, you can choose a method as `Static Parameters` where you need to assign the data yourself, or you can use a `Dynamic Parameter`, in this case, a string to fill the data.

Comment: two things:
1. the inspecter you showed does not look like mine & 
2. what do you mean by the input field object?

Comment: It does not have to look identical. I must just be in a different Unity version than you, which is fine. The `Input Field object` is the object that the user inputs to. You mentioned you have UI that takes user input, which should be a Unity.UI object called an InputField. When you click on this object the Unity inspector will fill with data pertaining to this object. Click it then follow the steps I listed.

Comment: Sorry for troubliing you but my method is not under the dynamic string list. It is under the static paramters list

Comment: @HumanFriend No worries. Did you add the string parameter to the function you are trying to call? And which version of Unity are you in?

Comment: I added the parameter like this:
```
public void debugInput(string str) {
        Debug.Log(str);
    }
```
I am in Unity 2019.4.17f1

Comment: Are you using an `InputField` or what UI object are you using to get user input? I am in a version close to yours and with a function, as you described, it should appear as a dynamic method. Are you dragging in the object with the script in your scene or dragging in a prefab or a script from the editor?

Comment: I am using a UI input field by right clicking then going to UI then clicking  input field.
I am dragging it from the inspecter

Comment: @HumanFriend The script you have **has** to exist on an object in your scene for this to work. You then drag in that object in your scene into the field, and then your method will appear.

Comment: @HumanFriend Did you end up getting your inputfield working?

Comment: Ahh yes. Sorry for not updating you here. I found this tutorial on Youtube where I used [Serialize Field] and 'On Edit End' 
Thank you for your help though!